# How do I programmatically disable built-in SSL on jelastic environments?

Tags: ssl, jelastic

In my Jelastic environment, I would like to disable built-in SSL. Through the Jelastic dashboard, it boils down to clicking on this:

[image]

and then switching it off by clicking the "on" button:

[image]

I am looking for the way to disable it through the Jelastic API. I tried to call the following methods, without success:

- jelastic.environment.binder.DisableSSL
- jelastic.environment.binder.DeleteSSL

Those two methods either do nothing or return the following error:

SSL certificate isn't bound inside container

How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way is to set `sslstate` via [changeTopology](https://docs.jelastic.com/api/#!/api/environment.Control-method-ChangeTopology) - but beware that you need to pass the whole environment topology perfectly matched to its existing state (node composition and cloudlets etc) to avoid any unwanted changes!

See network tab in browser devtools when performing this step via the dashboard for a full example.

Anything that you omit will be removed...

Comment: It cannot be that annoying. If that's really the case, I'll just fork the manifest I need and break the SSL lock directly there.

Answer (score 0):

It appears there is an undocumented api method that allows to do exactly what I want to do. Here's an example manifest illustrating that method:

```yaml
type: update
name: Disable SSL

onInstall:
  - jelastic.environment.control.editenvsettings:
      settings: 
        sslstate: false
```

The latest documentation I have access to, for Jelastic API v8.2.1, makes no mention of it. However, it works.